# Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I am getting an error in my angular app. On the client console I get:

```
Denying load of chrome-extension://fiekimdgbphfmnlbiahcfdgcipcopmep/js/lib/angular/angular.min.js.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
```

I supposed it has something to do with the way I am loading my javascripts:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Startup Jobs</title>

  <!-- Mobile Meta -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="StartupJobs" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />

  <!-- Typekit -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/zjd5rqh.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="/stylesheets/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">    

  <!-- Google Maps -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&language=en-US"></script>

  <!-- Angular + jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Plugins -->
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="/javascripts/components/infinite-scroll/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="/javascripts/components/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="/javascripts/components/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>


</head>
```

I have checked, all my routes are correct and the file should load properly. Note that I don't get the error with Firefox.
What could possibly go wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: something is trying to load up the file "angular.min.js.map", that file is not necessary for viewing pages, it's only for the developer for unminification. Presumably, one of your chrome extensions is blowing up because it's throwing an error that it can't access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chrome extension "Dragdis" was causing this error for me. Disabling it fixed the issue.

Comment: This answer solved my issue where I was getting the same error in my console regardless of which page I was accessing. I also have the Dragdis Chrome extension installed. The comment by @sksallaj was the clue!

Comment: This, provides an answer to the question, since I was having the same issue and disabling the extension solve it.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when using WebStorm. To correct it, I had to set the parent folder as the resource root.  Using WebStorm version 8.0.4, this can be done by right clicking the parent folder and selecting "mark directory as", then selecting "Resource Root"

Comment: I have no slightest idea how you figured it out, but it worked for me. Thanks.